# StackOverFlow in Postfix Decrement in JAVA

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

This works fine because we are using the prefix decrement operator in the recursive call !

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doubt1(5);
}
```

Prefix Decrement:

```java
static void doubt(int num)
{
    if(num==0)
        return;
    System.out.println(num);
    doubt(--num);
}
```

Postfix Decrement:

```java
static void doubt1(int num)
{
    if(num==0)
        return;
    System.out.println(num);
    doubt1(num--);
}
```

But when we use the postfix decrement it can lead to stack over flow error , I understand why it's causing the error , but I want to know , if we use `num-1` in the recursive call it doesn't give the overflow error , my question is -> why it's not giving the error coz it calculating the `num-1` and passing the value to the recursive call but not calculating the `num--` in the call ?

Want the explanation why it calculating the `num-1` not `num--` in the recursive call ? Not why it's happening !

Comment: Lets say num is 5. `doubt(num--)` is same as calling `doubt(5)`, whereas both of `doubt(num-1)` and `doubt(--num)` are the same as calling `doubt(4)` and num inside the nested call is now 4... and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
    doubt1(num--);
```

is internally implemented as

```
    int tmp = num;
    num = num - 1;
    doubt1(tmp);
```

That is, it recursively calls the `doubt1` method with the original value and therefore the condition `num == 0` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a method, the arguments are evaluated, and the resulting values are assigned as the initial values of the method's parameters.  The expressions `num--` and `--num` have the same side effect on `num`, but that is immaterial to the method invocation.  The two evaluate to different values: the former to the value of num *before* it is decremented, and the latter to the value of `num` *after* it is decremented.  The order of the operator relative to the operand is mnemonic for that.

Thus, with

```
int n = 1;
some_method(n--);
```

the value passed to `some_method()` is 1, but with

```
int n = 1;
some_method(--n);
```

the value passed to `some_method()` is 0.

In both cases, however, the value 0 is stored in `n` before execution of the body of `some_method()` commences.

Answer (score 0):

First, with the unary decrement operator, the operation is occurring after, or before, the *statement*.
As opposed to after, or before, the *expression*.

So, in this situation, there will be a difference between `num--` and `--num`.

- `doubt(num--)` is decrementing after the call statement, and not after the parameter expression.
- `double(--num)`, the opposite is happening, the decrement is happening before the parameter expression.

Essentially, from a compiler's stand-point, for the `doubt(--num)` statement, you have the following.

1. Get `num`
2. Decrement `num`
3. Apply `num` as `doubt` parameter
4. Execute `doubt` with parameter value

Alternately, with `doubt(num--)` you have the following.

1. Get `num`
2. Apply `num` as `doubt` parameter
3. Decrement `num` (which has no effect, since the parameter value was already set)
4. Execute `doubt` with parameter value

Essentially, for the `doubt(num--)` statement, after the compiler has `num`, and is ready to call `doubt`, it will then decrement `num`.
As opposed to having `num`, then decrementing, and then calling `doubt`.